# Python code - Cart items not getting displayed

Tags: python, list, sqlite

In my Python

```html
import os
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("m.db") #CHANGE THE NAME OF THE DATABASE EVERYTIME SINCE A DATABASE CANNOT HAVE TWO TABLES WITH THE SAME NAME CPU, ETC
def buyparts():
    print("========================================================================================================================================================")
    print("WELCOME TO ONLINE SHOPPING PORTAL")
    print("BEST PRICES GUARANTEED!")
    print("========================================================================================================================================================")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query1=("create table cpu(Model varchar(30), Platform varchar(10),Price integer)")
    cursor.execute(query1)
    query2=("insert into cpu values('Core i3 10th gen','Intel',12000)")
    cursor.execute(query2)

    try:
            CART=[]
            def cpu():
                    print("=============================")
                    print("CPU")
                    print("=============================")
                    sql= "select * from cpu"
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                    records = cursor.fetchall()
                    CPU=[]
                    for row in records:
                      sel=" "
                      print("=============================")
                      print("Model = ", row[0])
                      print("Platform = ", row[1])
                      print("Price  = ", row[2])
                      print("=============================")
                      sel=input("Do you want to place the order(Y/N)? Enter # to return to main menu ")
                      if sel.lower()=="y":
                        CPU=row
                        CART.append(CPU)                
                      elif sel.lower()=="n":
                        continue
                      elif sel.lower()=="#" :
                        return
                      else:
                        print("Invalid choice")
                        print("Program will be terminated")
                        exit()
                        return
                    print("No more products available ")
            
           
            
            def cartshow():
                    print("=============================")
                    print("MY CART")
                    print("=============================")
                    f=open("invoice.txt","a")
                    f.write("INVOICE")
                    f.write('/n')


                    total=0
                    for product in CART:
                        total+=product[2]
                        for i in product:
                            print(i,end=" ")
                            f.write(i)
                            f.write(" ")
                            
                        print()
                        f.write('/n')
                    
                    excl="Price exclusive of GST: RS.", total, "+18% GST"
                    print(excl)
                    net=(total*(18/100))+ total
                    incl="Price inclusive of GST: RS.", net
                    print(incl)
                    f.write(excl+'/n')
                    f.write(incl+'/n')
                    

                    f.close()
                    
                    sel=input("Do you want to place the order(Y/N)? Enter # to return to main menu ")
                    if sel.lower()=="y":
                      print("Order placed successfully")
                      print("Please view the invoice copy by going to the path: D:/invoice.txt")
                      print("Thank You for shopping with us ! ")
                      exit()

                    elif sel.lower()=="n" :
                      print("Order has been cancelled ")
                      CART.clear()
                      return
                    
                    elif sel.lower()=="#" :
                      return
                    
                    else:
                      print("Invalid choice")
                      print("Program will be terminated")
                      exit()
                      return
                  
            while True:     
                    print("========================================================================================================================================================")
                    L=(int(input("Enter the number assigned to the product which you want to view.\n 1.CPU\n 2.GPU\n 3.MOBO\n 4.RAM\n 5.PC CABINET\n 6.PSU\n 7.CPU COOLER\n 8.MY CART\n 9.EXIT\n")))
                    print("========================================================================================================================================================")
                    if L==1:
                        cpu()      
                    elif L==2:
                        gpu()
                    elif L==3:
                        mobo()
                    elif L==4:
                        ram()
                    elif L==5:
                        cab()
                    elif L==6:
                        psu()
                    elif L==7:
                        cooler()
                    elif L==8:
                        cartshow()
                    else:
                        cursor.close()
                        connection.close()
                        exit() 
          
    except:
        print("Error reading data from MySQL table")
        exit()
```

In my Python code snippet above, the **cartshow()** function is used to display all the items in the cart(a list). When I am trying to use the **cartshow()** function, only the first item that is appended in the list is getting displayed, and then it is directly going to the except() block. The remaining items are not displaying.

Could someone help me out, please?

Note - I have edited and included the snippets which are responsible for the error.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited; above is the required snippet

Comment: When you say it's going to the `except` block, what is the exception? Could you add a full stacktrace?